# Laravel 5.6 does is exists the way to pass some custom variable to Http Resource collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Model**

```
class Entity extends Model
{
    ...
}
```

**EntityResource** (the goal is to set theese resource fields dynamically)

```
public function toArray($request)
{        
    $fields = Field::byClassName(Entity::class)->get();

    foreach ($fields as $item) {
        $resource[$item->name] = data_get($this->resource, $item->name);
    }

    return $resource;
}
```

But, when I receive by this way resource collection, I have too many queries to db

```
$fields = Field::byClassName(Entity::class)->get();
```

as many as have resource items.

So, that would be good, if I set variable $fields (this collection is just some mapping of data) inside my controller and after pass it to resource collection method, some like this:

```
$fields = Field::byClassName(Entity::class)->get();
$entities = EntityResource::collection(Entity::all(), $fields); //doesn't work
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was applied a solution (not sure it is right)

Just put `$fields` to `$request`

```
$fields = Field::byClassName(Entity::class)->get();    
$request->request->add(compact('fields'));
```

And then, inside resource `toArray` method, get this variable, without any excess query to database

```
$fields = $request->fields;
```